# what is the computational complexity of Louvain algorithm?

Tags: algorithms, computational-complexity, approximation-algorithms, complex-networks

I am not able to find out the computational complexity of the Louvain Algorithm. Can anyone here help me? link of the paper given below:

DOI: 10.1088/1742-5468/2008/10/P10008

https://doi.org/10.1038/s41598-019-41695-z.

[image]

Comment: Apparently, it runs in time $O(n \log(n))$: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Louvain_method.

Comment: This $O(n\log(n))$ complexity is empirically observed on practical instance, but there is no proof, and I doubt non-trivial complexity is known.

Comment: The [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/0908.1062) cited in the Wikipedia article doesn't appear to actually state an $O(n\log(n))$ complexity for Louvain. They do claim without proof that it "is essentially linear in the number of links of the graph". Maybe I missed something?